# django admin custom time widget

Tags: django, django-admin

I am trying to override django's time widget.

```
if (!$) {
    $ = django.jQuery;
}

function overrideTimeOptions() {

   $('.timelist').each(function(num, el) {
        var time_format = '%H:%M';
        $(el).html('');
        for (var i=1; i<25; i++) {
            var time = new Date(1970,1,1,i,0,0);
            console.log(time)
            var lnk = "javascript:DateTimeShortcuts.handleClockQuicklink(" + num + ", '" + time.strftime(time_format) + "');"
            console.log("this is link");
            console.log(lnk);
            $(el).append('<li><a href="' + lnk + '">' + time.strftime(time_format) + '</a></li>');
        }

    });

}

setTimeout(function(){overrideTimeOptions()},500);
```

Here I can see the time options but when I click the time it gives me some weired value in the input field like `NaNaNa`

Can anyone help me on this whats going on here ??